# Report Builder - Keeping tables on same page that are aligned horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Ok, I have asked this question previously, but due to my lack of clarification I think it made it difficult to follow. Here is a simplified version of the issue I am trying to overcome. For the example, I have a report that has two tables of data from two separate datasets.  Both tables are grouped by column1 (Name).  Table1 is directly above Table2 as it shows in design mode.

The issue that I am having is Table2 will never show on the same page as Table1 when I render the report.  Each table will return only a couple of row, so forced page breaks due to page size and margins will not be an issue.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to working with two separate table because of having two separate datasets.

I think your best bet is to have table 2 as a Subreport.

Copy your current report and delete the Table 1 dataset and all the objects except table 2 from the new report. Add a parameter for the NAME field and filter the Table 2 dataset by that Name parameter.

Then add a subreport in the original report where table 2 was with the Table 1 Name field as the parameter for the subreport.

Add a List with Table 1 as the dataset and group by name. A List is like a table that you can add the page break Between to break up by Name.

Add another row in the List to the same group. Put your Table 1 in the top part of the List and the Subreport in the other one.

Now the list will show one name at a time one a page with the table 1 and then table 2.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

Create a rectangle and add your tables inside it therefore your tables will keep at same page with together.

Comment: Got it, thanks for that!  Ok upon giving that a shot I think I found what the issue is for my particular case.  I would like a have a page break after each "name", so that way the two tables and values for each person will show on its own page. My issue I believe is that in an attempt to do this, I added a page break to each row group in the two tables.  So I guess I am having a hard time on how to get both tables to show on the same page while at the same time returning one page per Name.